# Mi función e busqueda binaria no retorna una variable (C++)

Tags: c++, array, busqueda, binario

```
int binarySearch(vector<Datos> vectorBS, string x){ 
int inferior = 0;
int superior = vectorBS.size()-1;
bool flag = false;
while (inferior<=superior){
    int mitad = (inferior + superior) / 2; 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre == x){
        flag = true;
        break;  
    } 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre > x){
        superior = mitad;
        mitad = (inferior + superior)/2;
    } 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre < x){
        inferior = mitad;
        mitad = (inferior + superior)/2;
    }
}
if (flag == true){
    cout << "El nombre se encontró en la posicion " << mitad << endl;
    return mitad;
}
else{
    return -1;
}
```

}

esto es un codigo de busqueda binaria en un vector por nombres.
el problema es que al compilar me lanza el siguiente error:

tarea.cpp: In function ‘int binarySearch(std::vector, std::__cxx11::string)’:
tarea.cpp:245:55: error: ‘mitad’ was not declared in this scope
   cout << "El nombre se encontró en la posicion " << mitad << endl;
                                                       ^~~~~
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'BST' failed
make: *** [BST] Error 1

cual puede ser el problema? mitad está declarado dentro de la función y debería retornarlo cuando flag == true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿cual puede ser el problema? `mitad` está declarado dentro de la función y debería retornarlo cuando `flag == true`.

**Falso**.

`mitad` está declarado **dentro del `while`**.

C++ tiene el concepto de [*ámbito*](https://en.cppreference.com/book/scope); este se aplica a varios contexto. En tu caso, nos afecta el *ámbito de bloque*:

> #### Block Scope
>
> A block is delineated by an opening `{` and a closing `}`. Variables declared in a block are accessible from immediately after the declaration until the end of the block. Any sub-blocks declared within a block will have access to any variables declared in all scopes above it that are declared before the sub-block opens.

En traducción *muy mucho* libre por mi parte:

Un bloque está delimitado entre una llave de apertura `{` y otra de cierre `}`. Las variables declaradas en un bloque son accesibles desde inmediatamente después de la declaración hasta el final del bloque. Cualquier *bloque-hijo* declarado dentro de un *bloque-padre* tendrá acceso a cualquier variable declarada en todos los ámbitos por encima de él que sean declarados antes de que el *bloque-hijo* se abra.

La solución es, simplemente, **declarar la variable en un *bloque* superior**:

```
int binarySearch( vector< Datos > vectorBS, string x ) { 
  int inferior = 0;
  int superior = vectorBS.size()-1;
  bool flag = false;

  int mitad;

  while( inferior<=superior ) {
    mitad = ( inferior + superior ) / 2;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> error: ‘mitad’ was not declared in this scope

> error: ‘mitad’ no ha sido declarada en este ámbito

Te dice claramente que la variable no ha sido declarada en el ámbito en que es usada. Pero ¿Qué es el ámbito?

El [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf), tiene una sección dedicada al ámbito (traducción mía):

> #### 6.4.1 Regiones declarativas y ámbito
>
> Cada nombre es introducido en una porción determinada del programa llamada *región declarativa*, que es la parte más amplia del programa en que dicho nombre es válido, es decir, en la que ese nombre puede ser usado como nombre sin cualificar para referirse a la misma entidad. En general, cada nombre en particular es válido sólo dentro de ciertas porciones del programa que reciben el nombre de ámbito.

En general podemos decir que un ámbito empieza al abrir unas llaves (`{`) y finaliza al cerrarlas (`}`)<sup>1</sup>, por lo que tu variable `mitad`:

```
while (inferior<=superior){ // Inicio del ámbito del while
    int mitad = (inferior + superior) / 2; 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre == x){
        flag = true;
        break;  
    } 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre > x){
        superior = mitad;
        mitad = (inferior + superior)/2;
    } 
    if (vectorBS[mitad].nombre < x){
        inferior = mitad;
        mitad = (inferior + superior)/2;
    }
} // Fin del ámbito del while, la variable mitad no existe a partir de aquí.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>En general. En particular [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tiene 7 tipos diferentes de ámbito, también descritos en el estándar:

- Ámbito de bloque (§6.4.3).
- Ámbito de parámetro de función (§6.4.4).
- Ámbito de función (§6.4.5).
- Ámbito de espacio de nombres (§6.4.6).
- Ámbito de clase  (§6.4.7).
- Ámbito de enumerado (§6.4.8).
- Ámbito de parámetro de plantilla (§6.4.9).